# Gzcompressed or plain string

Tags: php, compression

I have a file `plain.cache` which is little over 10MB and I made a [gzcompressed](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzcompress.php) file `gz.cache` out of the original `plain.cache` file. Then, I made two separate files which load each of the mentioned cache files and was kind of surprised that the page load speed of both files was [almost the same](http://whichloadsfaster.com/?l=nikola-breznjak.com/_testings/plain.php&r=nikola-breznjak.com/_testings/gz.php). So, my question is - am I being right by concluding that `gzcompressed` file does not in any way benefit the load speed of the page? Now, I would conclude that the [gzuncompress](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzuncompress.php) that I use in the `gz.php` file "makes" the same exact string just as when I read it from the plain file. Given all these staments - a general question is how can I (if it all in all is done this way) increase the load speed by compressing the file with `gzcompress`.

The image of the files is below, and the code of files is as follows:

_makeCache.php, in which I make the gzcompressed version of the plain.cache file:

```
$str = file_get_contents("plain.cache");
$strCompressed = gzcompress($str, 9);

$file = "gz.cache";
$fp = fopen($file, "w");

fwrite($fp, $strCompressed);
fclose($fp);
```

plain.php:

```
echo file_get_contents("plain.cache");
```

gz.php:

```
echo gzuncompress(file_get_contents("plain.cache"));
```

[image]

Comment: any savings in reducing disk usage/disk system bandwidth is almost certainly going to get swallowed up by decompression overhead, plus the extra memory overhead to keep the compressed + uncompressed copies in memory (remember, file_get_contents doesn't return until the whole file's loaded).

Comment: so, basically, my conclusion is correct - right? Hmmm, given that - is there any other possibility of speeding the load up? As for example, I have a simple php file which loads a dozen of other plain txt files..

Comment: it's almost always better to load one single large-ish file than multiple small ones. each individual file will be bound by disk access latency and whatnot, plus open/read/close, blah blah blah. Of course, this is highly dependent on your disk system, ram/cpu speed, etc... you'd have to benchmark to figure out where the crossover point is.

Comment: Why not do a quick and easy benchmark where you repeat the process 100k times?  (Just remove the echo statements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your http server is compressing the plain.cache automatically on the fly, using gzip as well, and the client decompresses it.  So you should see almost no difference.